# Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL 2: All snaps are always "broken" after reboot

Tags: 20.04, snap, windows-subsystem-for-linux

1. Installed Ubuntu 20.04 distro on WSL 2
2. create `wsl.conf` as following:

```
===============================================================
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=11,case=off"
mountFsTab = true
crossDistro = true

[network]
generateHosts = false
generateResolvConf = true

[interop]
enabled = true
appendWindowsPath = true

=============================================================
```

3. Setup systemD according to
   https://github.com/damionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script
4. Install core, lxd and some other snaps like microk8s. Everything look fine:

`$ snap list`

```
Name      Version   Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes

core18    20210611  2074   latest/stable  canonical✓  base

core20    20210429  1026   latest/stable  canonical✓  base

lxd       4.15      20840  latest/stable  canonical✓  -

microk8s  v1.21.1   2262   1.21/stable    canonical✓  classic

snapd     2.51.1    12398  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

5. Logout
6. Login again, snaps status is the same
7. Logout and then terminate running distribution: wsl -t Ubuntu-20.04
8. Restart: wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04
9. Check snaps:

`$ snap list`

```
Name      Version  Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes

core18             2074   latest/stable  canonical✓  broken

core20             1026   latest/stable  canonical✓  broken

lxd       4.15     20840  latest/stable  canonical✓  -

microk8s           2262   1.21/stable    canonical✓  broken

snapd              12398  latest/stable  canonical✓  broken
```

I suspect snap configuration goes into temporary space and does not persist.